# How to refresh JTable with vectors

Tags: java, refresh, jtable, tablemodel

I have been stumped with this for quite some time now. I understand you use the table model to refresh the actual table with the new values however I cannot seem to get this to work.  I have added a tablemodellistener to my form and have a tableChanged method.  However, I cannot seem to figure out why the tableChanged method isn't getting called when I insert into a the table.

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int column = e.getColumn();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)e.getSource();
   // String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
    //Object data_1 = model.getValueAt(row, column);

    //model.fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    //model.fireTableDataChanged();
    //customerTable.repaint();


}
```

Could I completely rebuild the table if I click the refresh button on my form?  Would that at all be possible?  If not, do I have to call my tableChanged method from my refresh button's action performed method in order for it to trigger? I've been stuck on this for quite some time now and I would just like to get this figured out for the benefit of learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option and it fits your needs, I'd reccomend taking a look at [GlazedLists](http://www.glazedlists.com/). Then you won't have to worry about updating your table models--it's all handled for you.

Here's a jump to a [relevant part of the GlazedLists tutorial](http://www.glazedlists.com/documentation/tutorial-100#TOC-So-What-1).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to manually add your Table as Listener of table TableModel.